# Accessing one's profile using Facebook's Php Sdk & Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I wanted to create a small webpage in my website that shows all the activities(statuses) of ONLY **my** facebook account if anyone visits the page.

So I went over to the [facebook developers](http://developers.facebook.com) page and downloaded the PHP SDK and started experimenting. But soon I discovered the `access_token` thing. This literally wasted so much of my time. Since these access token only lasted for a little time and extended access token last only for like 60 days(I don't want to keep updating them a lot). I searched everywhere, but to no avail. I couldn't find a way in which I could access only MY facebook posts with FB's PHP SDK & Graph API. Can you guys help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have YOUR `access_token` to fetch the feeds from YOUR account. There's no other token you can use accept this token.

So it would be easier for you if you have a backend server (which I guess you must be having). You can write a small script, where you can call the facebook **login** and get the normal access token, then **extend** it to 60 days validity and save it to your database with its expiration date. And before it's getting expired just run the script and the token will be refreshed. And your main website will always fetch the token from the database. 
Simple enough. I don't think there's anything else you can do.

If you are interested in such a script, I can help you with it-

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code))
{ 
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                . "client_id=" . $APP_ID
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url);

    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
else 
{
    // access token
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                    . "client_id=" . $APP_ID
                    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                    . "&client_secret=" . $APP_SECRET
                    . "&code=" . $_REQUEST["code"];

    $response1 = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response1, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

    // extended token
    $extended_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                        . "grant_type=fb_exchange_token"
                        . "&client_id=" . $APP_ID
                        . "&client_secret=" . $APP_SECRET
                        . "&fb_exchange_token=" . $access_token;

    $response2 = file_get_contents($extended_token_url);
    $response2 = json_decode($response2);
    $extended_access_token = $params['access_token']; // save this to the database with the expiration date(current date+60days)
}
```

Comment: Will there be any problem if I replace `$_REQUEST['code']` with `$_GET['code']`?

Comment: I', not sure, but its what used in the official docs, you should  use the same